# FlatFileFooterCallback - Fixed Length Can It Be Done

Tags: spring-batch

I have a FlatFileItemWriter which writes my file to a fixed set of lengths using a FormatterLineAggregator. The full file gets written properly and life is good. I queried earlier that I also needed a footer written out that tells me how many records got written. I got this working, but I cannot figure out how to add the "formatter" so that my last line ends up being 1000 characters long. I am getting the footer written by implementing a FlatFileFooterCallback like so

`

```
@Value("#{StepExecution}")
private StepExecution stepExecution;

@Override
public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
    writer.write("H"+stepExecution.getWriteCount());
}
```

`

But this of course doesn't pad the line out to the 1000 I need for my downstream server to read properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder("H" + stepExecution.getWriteCount());

    for(int i = content.length(); i < 1000; i++) {
        content.append(" ");
    }

    writer.write(content.toString());
}
```